# Why does my while loop (z==0) runs multiple times after I set it to z==0 only once?

Tags: c, while-loop

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {

    int x,y,z=0,number,digit;
    char c;
    int sum = 0;
    int temp = 0;

    while (z==0){

        printf("enter 2-9 for hex\n");
        scanf("%c",&c);
        x = (int)c-48;
        if((int)c>49 && (int)c<59){
            printf("enter number");
            scanf("%d",&number);
            break;
        }
        else if ((int)c<50 || (int)c>58){
            printf("wrong number\n");
            z==0;
        }
        else
            printf("error");
            z==0;

    }
while (number != 0) {
        digit = number % 10;
        number = number / 10;
        if (digit >= x) {
            printf("wrong input!!!");
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            int temp1 = temp;
            if (temp1 == 0) {
                digit = digit * 1;
            }
            else {
                while (temp1 != 0) {
                    digit = digit * x;
                    temp1--;
                }
            }
        }
        sum = sum + digit;
        temp = temp + 1;
    }
    printf("\nThe number in Decimal is:%d", sum);

}
```

This is my code, its about transforming hex into decimals.The question is when I enter 2-9 everything is good, but when I enter 1, the first while loops for 2 times, if I enter 10-99 it loops 3 times, if I enter 100-999 it loops 4 times etc...

**Why is it that it still runs multiple times after I set Z==0;**

Comment: If you want to set `z` to be `0`, write `z=0;` not `z==0;`.  The latter checks whether `z` equals zero and then does nothing with the answer, and doesn't change the value of `z`.  A decent compiler will warn you about this, if you turn on warnings.

Comment: See how you have assigned 0 to `z` here: `int x,y,z=0`. Don't you think you just need the same?

Comment: @NateEldredge I tried what you said and wrote while(x =0) and in else x=0 but the whole while loop just got skipped entirely, i also changed int z=0; to int z;

Comment: You really need to understand what the `=` and `==` operators actually do.  `=` sets a value, `==` tests.  Think carefully about which one you want in which situation.  At present it seems like you're making changes at random without understanding what you're doing, and that will not work in the long run.

Comment: Though there are typos (a lot!) the problem is not caused by typos but by bad style and thinkos. Asking to reopen...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the situation is you condition of z is all the time true. Your start condition i z == 0, this starts the while loop. The while loop stops, when z is not more 0. So somewhere in your while loop, you have to change z at be not zero. Then your while loop stops. And please use closing and opening "{}" for if-else. That helps and increases readability.

for example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {

    int x,y,z=0,number,digit;
    char c;
    int sum = 0;
    int temp = 0;

    while (z==0){

        printf("enter 2-9 for hex\n");
        scanf("%c",&c);
        x = (int)c-48;
        if((int)c>49 && (int)c<59){
            printf("enter number");
            scanf("%d",&number);
            break;
        }
        else if ((int)c<50 || (int)c>58){
            printf("wrong number\n");
            z==0;
        }
        else {
            printf("error");
            z==0;
}
z = 1;
    }
while (number != 0) {
        digit = number % 10;
        number = number / 10;
        if (digit >= x) {
            printf("wrong input!!!");
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            int temp1 = temp;
            if (temp1 == 0) {
                digit = digit * 1;
            }
            else {
                while (temp1 != 0) {
                    digit = digit * x;
                    temp1--;
                }
            }
        }
        sum = sum + digit;
        temp = temp + 1;
    }
    printf("\nThe number in Decimal is:%d", sum);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This still has the bug with `z==0` instead of `z=0`.

Comment: @NateEldredge The `z==0;` does nothing. `z=0;` would also do nothing , since z is already zero. So it is nonsensensical, but not the actual bug causing the problems.